# What IMS packages are available for Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, voip

Im am building an unified messaging platform on Ubuntu, including VOIP and other features. However I need to modify the existing codebase, so that it works on top of IMS (IP Multimedia Subsystem). I am aware of one IMS implementation for Linux ([Open IMS Core](http://www.openimscore.org/)), but it is mostly designed for testbed and not for production systems. Can you point me to some other IMS implementations, possibly free, for Linux?

Regards,
Angel Kafazov

Comment: Please, don't use signature, as all information about you can be found in your bio, which is linked by the logo you see in the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a HSS system written in erlang....

there are also some other components written on top of kamillio SIP i think it might be called openHSS...

mobicents has some tutorials about linking with an openIMS

an IMS implementation consists of many components so you wont likely find an entire system freely open sourced

your closet bets are the mobicents and opencloud Slee platforms
but Beware JSLEE dev is a complex beast